# Adding multiple new shipping methods

Tags: third-party-module

I'm following the guide located at http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

but I'm unsure if this allows me to add multiple shipping methods. I could install the module multiple times but I'm not sure this is the best way if the class supports multiple shipping methods.

The question here is, does the above tutorial allow me to add multiple shipping methods under 1 module?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an article from another website. You should try and post comment at inchoo instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple shipping methods into one module, for example the fedex module will display all the available shipping type (Overnight, 2 Business Days ...)

```
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

....

$rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
$rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
$rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
$rate->setMethod('large');
$rate->setMethodTitle('Overnight');
$rate->setPrice(5);
$rate->setCost(0);
// append first shipping type
$result->append($rate);


$rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
$rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
$rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
$rate->setMethod('large');
$rate->setMethodTitle('2 Business Days');
$rate->setPrice(10);
$rate->setCost(0);
// append second shipping type
$result->append($rate);

....
```

Comment: Do you know how could achieven this in mangento 2?

Comment: @JulianoVargas ... Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/magento2-custom-shipping-rate/blob/master/Model/Carrier.php#L104

Comment: @JulianoVargas I am also trying to achieve the same in Magento 2. Have you got the solution?